# Filtering git commits by the number of lines in the commit message

Tags: git, git-commit

I'm trying to find long (verbose) git commits which includes over a certain number of lines in the message body — say commit messages with more than 3 lines (aside from the title line).

Is there a way to achieve this?

The goal is to showcase clear and descriptive commit messages in our codebase or find good examples of long commit messages in open source repositories.

Comment: Far from a complete answer, but I'm guessing that `--log-size`, will be part of your solution. `git log --log-size` gives you the size of each log entry in bytes.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned above, git log has the flag '-log-size'

```
# use the --log-size flag to view the size of the commit message
# add the -online to make the output more compact
git log --log-size --oneline
```

> #### --log-size
>
> Include a line `log size '' in the output for each commit, where  is the length of that commit's message in bytes.
>
> Intended to speed up tools that read log messages from `git log output by allowing them to allocate space in advance.

Comment: It seems strange this option doesn't include some way to count lines. It almost seems as if parsing the `\n` characters from the log messages themselves would be an easier way to achieve what I'm looking for. No?